# Showing $A_4$ is a subgroup of $SU(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

I am trying to show that $A_4$ is a subgroup of $SU(2).$

We know that $A_4$ is a group of even permutations of four elements, and that $SU(2)$ is the Lie group of $2\times 2$ unitary matrices with determinant $1$. So how can we show that?

I'll be thankfull for having answers.

Comment: Up to conjugation it is enough to realise $A_4$ as subgroup of $GL_2(\Bbb C)$. This is explained, for example, [here](http://www.math.rug.nl/~top/INDAG171.pdf).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am missing something. [The irreducible representations of $A_4$ have dimensions $1,1,1,3$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_alternating_group:A4). And the sum of two 1-dimensional representations is not faithful, because the commutator subgroup is in the kernel. The usual averaging trick does lead to unitary matrices, but the other problem needs to be solved first.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ...and your comment shows that $A_4$ *is not* a subgroup of $SU(2)$. I think there is probably confusion here between $SU(2)$ and its quotient $SO(3)$. Of course $A_4$ (the "tetrahedral group") is a subgroup of $SO(3)$.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40351/what-are-the-finite-subgroups-of-su-2c?noredirect=1&lq=1).