# Is $ SU_2(\Bbb Z[1/\sqrt{2}]) $ finite?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $ G=SU_2(\mathbb{Z}[1/\sqrt{2}]) $ be the group of $ 2 \times 2 $ unitary determinant one matrices with entries whose real and imaginary parts are from $\mathbb{Z}[i,1/\sqrt{2}]$.

Is $ G $ finite?

For $ SU_2(\mathbb{Z}[1/\sqrt{p}]) $ for $ p=3,5 $ etc I have already found some matrices of infinite order. But for $ p=2 $ I am having difficulty finding any matrices of infinite order or any other indication that $ G $ is infinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not finite. This is closely related to the Golden Gates in quantum computation. Roughly, not only the group is not finite, its elements can actually be used to approximate any element in $PU(2)$. Details can be found in [the notes by Peter Sarnak](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Sum%20of%20squares%20and%20golden%20gates.pdf).

To illustrate the key ideas, with some effort, we can show that any element in $G$ can be written as $$g=\frac{1}{2^{h/2}}\begin{pmatrix} x_1+x_2i && x_3+x_4i \\ -x_3+x_4i && x_1 - x_2i\end{pmatrix}$$ where $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\in \mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ and $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=2^h$. (It's slightly harder to show the decomposion exsits, but it's straightforward to show such a matrix indeed lies in $G$, which is all we need.)

Now let $x_1=\sqrt 2 + 1, x_2 = \sqrt 2 - 1, x_3 = \sqrt 2, x_4 = 2\sqrt 2, h=4$. And to show $g$ has inifnite order, we only need to show its eigenvalues are not roots of unity. Since $\det(g)=1, \text{Tr}(g)=\frac{2}{2^{h/2}} x_1=\frac{x_1}{2}$, the characteristic polynomial is $$\lambda^2-\frac{x_1}{2}\lambda + 1 = 0$$

Let $\cos(\theta)=\frac{x_1}{4}=\frac{\sqrt 2 + 1}{4}$, then we have $\lambda = \cos(\theta) \pm i \sin\theta=e^{i\theta}$. Now it suffices to show $\theta$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$. OK... I don't how to do this, but if $e^{i\theta}$ is a root of unity, so is $e^{-i\theta}$, hence $2\cos(\theta)=e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}$ is integral but $\frac{x_1}{2}=\frac{\sqrt 2 + 1}{2}$ is not.

Comment: Fabulous answer! I'll probably just post this as a new question but would you happen to know if there are finitely many elements in $ SU_2(\mathbb{Z}[1/\sqrt{2}]) $ of finite order? If so, would you happen to know if they form a group?

Comment: I haven't checked the details, but I'm pretty sure there are infinitely many elements of finite order: Pick some finite order elements, and then conjugate it with lots of other elements. (Or if you can show directly any conjugacy class is infinite).  From this, it should be also clear that they don't form a group. A more interesting question is what kind of finite group can be found in it, and we know $H$ and $T$ (as in Sarnak's notes, page 16) generate a group of order 24, the Clifford group, but $H$ and $T$ don't have det $1$, which can be fixed I guess.

Comment: Ya you are definitely right that torsion set is not a finite group it looks like $ T24 $ in this Sarnak paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.02106.pdf  is order $ 2 $ if we normalize the determinant and it generates an infinite subgroup  of $ SU_2(\mathbb{Z}[1/\sqrt{2}]) $.

Comment: And for the question about finite subgroup of $ SU_2(\mathbb{Z}[1/\sqrt{2}]) $ ya that definitely interesting. You are referring to the part in Sarnak where he says "The gates H and S generate exactly 24 gates,
called the Clifford gates." He means that the image of those two gates in $ PU_2 $ generates a group of size 24 (its isomorphic to $ S_4 $). Even if you normalize the determinant of $ H, S $ they generate a subgroup of $ SU_2 $ of size $ 48 $ (isomorphic to $ GL_2(3) $, sometimes called the binary ocahedral group, its a central extension of $ S_4 $ by $ \pm 1 $).

Comment: The actual matrices $ H, S $ themselves generate a group of size $192$ which is just a direct product of this group of size 48 with a cyclic group of order 4 (generated by $ i=det(S) $). $ SU_2 $ does contain an interesting group of size 24 which is a subgroup of $SU_2(\mathbb{Z[1/\sqrt{2}]})$ but this group of size $24$ is not generated by $H,S$ rather it is generated by (the determinant 1 version of) the product $ HS $ together with $iZ:=diag(i,-i)$.  This group is $SL_2(3)\cong 2.A_4$,  the binary tetrahedral group. The ADE classification of $SU_2$ finite subgroups shows there are no others

Comment: Just correcting an error in my previous comment. There is no subgroup of $ SU(2) $ isomorphic to $ GL_2(3) $. The group of order $ 48 $ generated by determinant 1 version of $ H,S $ is actually GAP ID SmallGroup(48,28). See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4398724/758507 for details

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: My earlier "answer" was toooooo glib, and not accurate! EDIT-EDIT: some precise details filled in...

In general, we should tend to expect that a semi-simple algebraic group's points over a localization of the defining ring (here $\mathbb Z$, actually), is infinite, for general reasons related to Strong Approximation.

In the present example, there is a potentially confusing point, that the definition of the group seems to involve $i=\sqrt{-1}$... yes, but the points of the algebraic group using $i$ in their coordinates are defined over $\mathbb Q$, not $\mathbb Q(i)$. Namely, if $G$ is the standard $SU(2)$, and $A$ is a $\mathbb Z$-algebra, what is $G(A)$? It is $\{g\in GL_2(\mathbb Z[i]\otimes_{\mathbb Z} A):g^*g=1_2, \;\det g=1\}$. That is, the appearance of complex numbers is an artifact of the construction.

Partly to avoid that pitfall, and partly to have a more efficient approach with this small group, we use the isomorphism of $SU(2)$ with Hamiltonian quaternions $\mathbb H^1$ of norm $1$. Specifically, letting $\mathbb H_{\mathbb Q}=\{a+bi+cj+dk: a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Q\}$, the isomorphism $H^1_{\mathbb Q}\to SU(2)(\mathbb Q)$ is by
$$
a+bi+cj+dk\;\to\;\pmatrix{a+bi & c+di \cr c-di & a-bi}
$$
For a $\mathbb Z$-algebra $A$, the $A$-valued points of the group are identified with the elements of $\mathbb H\otimes_{\mathbb Z} A$ with (extended) norm $1$.

Without worrying about adjoining $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, and such things, and/or their inverses, we can address a more direct question: for prime $p$, does $G(\mathbb Z[1/p])$ have any infinite-order elements? The discussion of *impossibility* is a little simpler than the case of *possibility*, and we are perhaps most immediately interested in $A=\mathbb Z[1/2]$, as a preliminary to $A=\mathbb Z[1/\sqrt{2}]$.

If an element $\alpha$ of infinite order were in $G(\mathbb Z[1/2])$, then $\mathbb Q_2(\alpha)$ is an extension $k$ of $\mathbb Q$ of either degree one or two, since it is inside the quaternion algebra $\mathbb H_{\mathbb Q}$. Since $G(\mathbb Z)$ is finite, the extension must be of degree $2$. By Hilbert's Theorem 90, since it has norm $1$, $\alpha=\beta/\beta^\sigma$ for some $\beta$ in $k$. If $\beta=\beta^\sigma$, this is just the identity, not of infinite order. Meanwhile, $\sigma$ is of order two. Thus, it cannot be that $\beta^\sigma=u\cdot \beta$ with a unit $u$ other than $u=\pm 1$. Thus, the only way to make such $alpha$ is as $\beta/\beta^\sigma$ with $\beta$ divisible by at least one prime $\pi$ that has split in the extension. That is, for some rational $p$ splitting as $p=\pi_1\cdot \pi_2$, take $\alpha=\pi_1/\pi_2$.

Of course, the ring of integers $\mathfrak o_k$ in $k$ may not be a PID, but its class number $h$ is finite, so even if $p$ splits into non-principal ideals $\pi_1$, $\pi_2$, the power $\pi_1^h$ and $\pi_2^h$ are principal, and we can manufacture $\alpha$.

Indeed, this trick succeeds for any quadratic extension $k$ of $\mathbb Q$ that admits an imbedding to the rational Hamiltonian quaternions, since all primes $p\ge 3$ *split* these quaternions, there is no constraint at any primes other than $2$ and $\infty$. At $\infty$, the quadratic (algebra) extension $k$ must be $\mathbb C$ (as opposed to $\mathbb R\oplus \mathbb R$).

So, with a little work, $G(\mathbb Z[1/p])$ has torsion elements for any $p\ge 3$. We don't even need $1/\sqrt{p}$.

In contrast, since $\mathbb H_{\mathbb Q}$ is ramified at $2$, there is no quadratic extension $k$ of $\mathbb Q$ splitting at $2$ that imbeds into that quaternion algebra. So there are no elements of infinite order in $G(\mathbb Z[1/2])$.

But, still, what about $1/\sqrt{2}$? If this extension splits the quaternion algebra, then the construction above will succeed in producing an infinite-order element... :)

Comment: Interesting. Could you give an example of $ u,v $ such that $ x,y \in \mathbb{Z}[1/\sqrt{2}] $ and $$ \begin{pmatrix} x+iy & 0 \\ 0 & x-iy \end{pmatrix} $$ has infinite order? Or an example of an infinite family of $ u,v $ such that $ x,y \in \mathbb{Z}[1/\sqrt{2}] $? It is not clear to me from your answer that either construction is possible.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira, hm, this may be more difficult than I'd thought... let me think... :) :)